# How to pass class method as parameter in C++11/14?

Tags: c++, c++11

Note: I have modified the original post so to produce a minimal verifiable example.

I apologized if this has been answered before but I couldn't find it. I'm trying to move from the old pointer to function C-style.

Below I have a class `SolverNonTemplate` that calculates a function that is passed to it. This works for anonymous functions `functionToEval`. I do need though `functionToEval` to be passed from a different class instantiation that both parametrizes and add more structure to the problem to be solved (represented simplistically by struct `SetSystem`).

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015. The compiler error is:

```
Error C3867 'SetSystem::DumbSystem': non-standard syntax; use '&'
to create a pointer to member   main.cpp 55.
```

Code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class SolverNonTemplate {
public:
    template<typename Lambda>
    void evaluateFunction(const std::vector<double>& varsToSolveValues,
                          Lambda&& functionToEval,
                          std::vector<double>& functionValsOut)
    {
        for (int ifunc = 0; ifunc < varsToSolveValues.size(); ++ifunc)
        {
            functionValsOut[ifunc] = std::forward<Lambda>(functionToEval)(varsToSolveValues, ifunc);
        }
    }

};

double DumbSystem(const std::vector<double>& varsToSolveValues, int indexToReturn)
{
    if (indexToReturn == 0) {
        return varsToSolveValues[0] * varsToSolveValues[0] - varsToSolveValues[1] * varsToSolveValues[1]; //x^2 - y^2
    }
    else {
        return varsToSolveValues[0] * varsToSolveValues[0] * varsToSolveValues[0] - varsToSolveValues[0] + varsToSolveValues[1]; //x^3 - x*y
    }
}

struct  SetSystem
{
    double DumbSystem(const std::vector<double>& varsToSolveValues, int indexToReturn)
    {
        if (indexToReturn == 0) {
            return varsToSolveValues[0] * varsToSolveValues[0] - varsToSolveValues[1] * varsToSolveValues[1]; //x^2 - y^2
        }
        else {
            return varsToSolveValues[0] * varsToSolveValues[0] * varsToSolveValues[0] - varsToSolveValues[0] + varsToSolveValues[1]; //x^3 - x*y
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> x0Guess = { -30.0, 11.5 };
    std::vector<double> fValuesOut;
    fValuesOut.resize(2);
    SolverNonTemplate solver;
    solver.evaluateFunction(x0Guess, DumbSystem, fValuesOut);
    std::cout << " using anonymous functions.." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "dumbSystem f[0] = " << fValuesOut[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << "dumbSystem f[1] = " << fValuesOut[1] << std::endl;

    std::cout << "now trying to use function from struct/class /n";
    SetSystem system;
    SolverNonTemplate solver2;
    solver2.evaluateFunction(x0Guess, system.DumbSystem, fValuesOut);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You mustn't forward something more than once. Forwarding is conceptually like moving.

Comment: What do you mean? You use your functionToEval as a plain function. A "function that is a member of another class" only makes sense if you have an object for which you want to call a method.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], with the compiler error included. It's completely unclear what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use `&` for taking a function's address (for both free or member), it makes your intention clearer.

Then you can't use `system.DumbSystem` for passing a function with all that goes with it (attributes values and so forth (see 1)). Functions are bounded to a class and `this` is an implicit first argument for every function member. You need to pass an object and a function, that is done with `std::bind`

```
#include <functional>
//....
using std::placeholders::_1;
using std::placeholders::_2;
solver2.evaluateFunction(x0Guess, std::bind(&SetSystem::DumbSystem,std::ref(system),_1,_2), fValuesOut);
```

You also could use a lambda to achieve the same effect.

Finally, I'm pretty sure that the `std::forward` in `evaluateFunction` is useless (but I don't think it's harmful). You forward an argument *to another function* so that it keeps its rvalue-ness/lvalue-ness. Here you are forwarding to nobody.

---

1: IMO, That would be an elegant way to create a closure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the address of the function, that is, `solver.evaluateFunction(x0Guess, &DumbSystem, fValuesOut);`. Btw, I'd recommend you to consider `std::function<...>` instead of a simple template if you can accept its overhead, as this is exactly what it's designed for.